# How to install Master PDF Editor in Kubuntu 12.04 (64bit)

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, repository, master-pdf-editor

How to install Master PDF Editor under Kubuntu? I do not have it in the repositories.

Could somebody write it step by step?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Under stock Ubuntu you can easily install Master PDF Editor through the Ubuntu Software Center, as long as you have a USC account. I am not familiar with software installation on Kubuntu, but isn't there a way to install the Ubuntu Software Center under KDE? If so, you could try that.

Answer (score 4):

Well, then the best answer I could offer boils down to downloading the tarball file from master pdf editor website, unzipping it and then running the executable file from there. This boils down to the following steps in terminal:

```
wget http://code-industry.net/public/PDFEditor-1.7.91.x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf PDFEditor-1.7.91.x86-64.tar.gz
cd /home/username/PDFEditor
./pdfeditor
```

If this fails, then I'm afraid I haven't the foggiest what I can say that will help you.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer! That worked out!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - the *buy* button in my Ubuntu Software Centre is greyed out and unclickable. To install other programs, I got around that by using the '*install*' option in the menu bar, under *File*. But in this case, for Master PDF Editor, even that is greyed out!!

So the only option remaining for me was to use the terminal - **but how**?

---

[This blog in Spanish](http://emilianoangel.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/master-pdf-xps-editor-v-1-7-en-fedora-17-2/) provides accurate instructions.

I paraphrase its pith here:

for 32-bit Ubuntu, use

```
cd /opt && sudo wget http://code-industry.net/public/PDFEditor-1.7.01.i386.tar.gz && sudo tar -zxvf PDFEditor-1.7.01.i386.tar.gz && sudo rm PDFEditor-1.7.01.i386.tar.gz
```

for 64-bit Ubuntu, use

```
cd /opt && sudo wget http://code-industry.net/public/PDFEditor-1.7.01.x86_64.tar.gz && sudo tar -zxvf PDFEditor-1.7.01.x86_64.tar.gz && sudo rm PDFEditor-1.7.01.x86_64.tar.gz
```

Comment: Why can't you add sudo before all the commands in the line. For example insert sudo in between each of the && and whatever comes next. Enter your password and you are done. The Method 1 is not recommended for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I was having some issues with this, but then I went straight to the Master PDF site and was able to download the .deb file and installed through Ubuntu Software Center without issues:

x86: http://code-industry.net/public/master-pdf-editor_2.1.00_i386.deb

x64: http://code-industry.net/public/master-pdf-editor_2.1.00_amd64.deb

Hope this might help someone!

~Ken

Answer (score 0):

Tried downloading and installing PDF Mod? It allows you to modify PDFs, albeit its probably not the best of PDF editing tools but it's a start at least. Just open up software centre and type, 'PDF Mod' click install and wait.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! I have tried Pdf Mod already, but it sometimes does not work with some types of pdf files...and Master Pdf Editor looks to have more functions. I have found lately not a bad program - uPdf. It has quite a lot of functions, but design still lacks back.

Comment: I have found a way around: 1. Install UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER without installing any other Ubuntu programs through:                                                       sudo apt-get install software-center --no-install-recommends             2. Now you can install the program from the center itself